# Is the 1-dimension projective line a circle?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is the 1 dimensional projective line homeomorphic to the circle?  If so, the circle is homeomorphic to itself with antipodal points identified  (very unintuitive).  I am missing something?

Comment: They are homeomorphic. Why do you think you are missing something?

Comment: My intuition would say that like the sphere, if you identify antipodal points you should change the structure, not end up with what you started with.

Comment: @user54301 Have you ever taken a rubber band and doubled it to form a smaller loop?  It's pretty easy for a rubber band, but not so obvious for a rubber sphere :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the real $1$-dimensional projective line $\mathbb{RP}^1$ is homeomorphic (in fact diffeomorphic) to the circle $S^1$. It can be thought of as the circle $S^1$ with antipodal points identified, which reflects the fact that the circle is its own double cover: the double cover map is given explicitly by

$$S^1 \ni z \mapsto z^2 \in S^1$$

thinking of $S^1$ as the unit complex numbers. In other words, quotienting by antipodes is the same as quotienting by $180^{\circ}$ rotation; note that this is very much false for the 2-sphere.

Comment: I see each point, individually.  Should I be thinking of the nature projective planes as closely related to covers?  Even for non-spheres?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a somewhat lower-brow 'proof by picture' of how such a process of gluing might go. To save you from having to read my poor handwriting, the steps are:

1) Embed $S^1$ into the $(x,y)$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

2) Pick an antipodal pair and glue (together) to the $z$-axis.

3) Pick another pair of non-glued antipodal points, and snip the two loops at this pair.

4) Glue the antipodal pairs of line segments (together) along the $z$-axis.  You'll have but one pair left unglued.

5) Glue final pair.

[image]